# First time with PIL, unsure what this error is

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to take an image and superimpose it onto another about 5,000 times. I have a for loop that allowed me to flip an image horizontally, but when trying to superimpose I'm getting an error. I'm new-ish to Python so I may be missing something simple, but i've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out. Thank you for any help!

```
import os
from PIL import Image

file_list = os.listdir("C:\\Users\\blake\\apebase\\ipfs")


for x in file_list:     
    
    org_img = Image.open("C:\\Users\\blake\\apebase\\ipfs\\" + (x))
    

    background = Image.open(org_img)
    foreground = Image.open("C:\\Users\\blake\OneDrive\\Pictures\\saveas.png")

    background.paste(foreground, (0,0), foreground)
    background.show()

    org_img.save("rightClick"+ (x) +".png")
```

From the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\blake\Righ Click Save.py", line 12, in <module>
    background = Image.open(org_img)
  File "C:\Users\blake\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2962, in open
    prefix = fp.read(16)
  File "C:\Users\blake\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 519, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: read
```

Comment: What is "an error"? Please paste the full traceback of the error into your post.

Comment: `Image.open` expects a string argument. When you do `background = Image.open(org_img)`, you are passing in an image object, not a string.

Comment: Paul M. thank you, this was all i needed. really appreciate the help!